# Create comma separated selectors with Less loop

Tags: css, less

Currently I'm using the Less code below to create the defaults for my grid elements:

```
.create-grid-elements(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    .grid_@{i} {
        position: relative;
        display:inline;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .create-grid-elements(@n, @i+1);
}

.create-grid-elements(16);
```

which outputs:

```
.grid_1 {
    ...
}

.grid_2 {
    ...
}

...

.grid_16 {
    ...
}
```

For the sake of debugging using browser dev tools, is there a way to tweak the loop (or write a new loop) such that instead of writing multiple independent selectors for the grid, it instead writes one selector that is comma separated like this?

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, ... , .grid_16 {
    ...
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`extend()`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature):

> Extend is a Less pseudo-class which merges the selector it is put on with ones that match what it references.

Just create a base class, in this case `.grid_1`.

Then [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) it inside the loop: `.grid_@{i}:extend(.grid_1) {}`.

Since the base class is being extended, it doesn't need to be included in the loop. The index now starts at 2.

```
.grid_1 {
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.create-grid-elements(@n, @i: 2) when (@i =< @n) {
    .grid_@{i}:extend(.grid_1) {}
    .create-grid-elements(@n, @i+1);
}

.create-grid-elements(16);
```

Output:

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4,
.grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8,
.grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12,
.grid_13, .grid_14, .grid_15, .grid_16 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my team's using a version of less before v1.4.0 when the extend pseudo class was added.  However, this works perfectly with the current version.